# Digital Membership Card for Apple and Google Wallet

Tags: civimember

I'm looking for a solution to allow civiCRM to create a digital membership card that can be emailed to members so they can add them to Apple and Google Wallet.

Has anyone worked on this (or have a solution already)?

Or have an integration with PassKit's API?

Comment: Are you trying integrate with something?

Comment: Since my original post, requirements have been clarified... Ideally, we're looking for a civiCRM extension that at simple level on the Membership page for a contact would allow for "Creating" or "Revoking" a digital membership card via PassKit's API.

Comment: maybe title needs an update?